# iOS Wikitude Google Maps SDK Did not clear context upon block exist

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios, wikitude

I am using Wikitude SDK for augmented reality. It works ok.

Google Maps SDK for iOS work fine.

Problem is when I turn on Wikitude SDK and then I try using Google Maps SKD.

On Console I receive information:

"Did not clear context upon block exist"

On second try Google Maps doesn't render a map.

What should I do to fix this problem. Mapkit doesn't have this problem but my boss wants to use Google Maps SDK. I don't want to write a app with single ViewController.

I searched Google for phrase "Did not clear context upon block exist" but I didn't find anything.

Edit:
I am using iOS 7 SDK with Xcode 5. Wikitude draw point on camera. On Google Maps SDK I just insert markers on map. Nothing special. Everything works fine just one thing trigger something another as programmer I know I am in deep trouble. I don't know what is happening inside this SDKs.

I am also using container views to separate map and my view with buttons .

Comment: Can you provide more information such as your development environment and the code you are using to instantiate your library APIs?

Comment: To be honest I can even send to you my demo code that show this problem. :) I happy that someone respond to me. I will update my question again with code but I know this maybe doesn't help much.

Comment: Please file a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Bug) with a short repro code sample. Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't attach demo example because Google SDK and Wikitude are too huge so I give you url to my dropbox. Here is my bug report: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps iOS API version 6.1 resolved that bug.

I should thank Google developers for fix and Wikitude developers for help on forum.
[Wikitude forum](http://developer.wikitude.com/developer-forum/-/message_boards/view_message/386988)